# Проблемы с получением даныых в Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

Выполняю поиск по своей базе данных в firebase, используя такой код:

```
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Рецепты");
    Query query_search = myRef.orderByChild("Ингридиенты").startAt("Молоко, яблоки");
    query_search.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value_name = dataSnapshot.child("Имя").getValue(String.class);
            text.setText(value_name);
```

где `text` - объект `TextView`

В результате выполнения кода я хочу получить поле `Имя` того рецепта, в который входит ингридиенты `Яблоки, молоко`

Код выполняется для базы данныых с вот такой структурой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По непонятным мне причинам, после выполнения кода `text` - пусть, а `value_name = null`

Как это исправить?

**upd**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если вы хотите, чтобы в выборку попадали все рецепты, где есть, условно, яблоки и молоко, ваши ингредиенты должны быть в БД каждый отдельно (связь многие ко многим), а не в одну строку. Так как у вас сейчас, вы сможите найти только по точному совпадению всей строки, а не отдельных нужных ингридиентов

Comment: @pavlofff Я изменил структуру своей бд, вы можете увидеть его в моем вопросе. Цель осталась прежней: Пользователь выбирает несколько ингридиентов, пускай это будет например пользователь выбирает `Sugar` и `Carrot` и в результате должен получить `Carrot Salad`

Answer (score 0):

`startAt("Молоко, яблоки");`

Здесь нужно написать точно так же как в базе, то есть `("Яблоки, молоко")`. Поменяй местами.